# Using Tweepy to get live tweets from single user

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I'm trying to retrieve tweets from a single user_id as per the JSON data tweepy fetches.

The issue is im also retrieving all mentions of the user_id i.e. other people mentioning the user_id in any way (RT, Mentions etc)

I have quoted my script below. Please let me know if this is possible in tweepy at all.

the snippet `streamer.filter(follow = ['25073877'], encoding = 'utf8')` shows which user i am wanting to follow

Thank you in advance.

```
from __future__ import print_function
import tweepy
import json
import MySQLdb 
from dateutil import parser
import Twitter_API
import DBConfig

Access_Token = ""
Access_Token_Secret = ""
Consumer_Key = ""
Consumer_Secret = ""

class StreamListener(tweepy.StreamListener):    


def on_connect(self):
    print("You are now connected to the streaming API.")

def on_error(self, status_code):
    print('An Error has occured: ' + repr(status_code))
    return False

def on_data(self, data):
    try:
       # Decode the JSON from Twitter
        datajson = json.loads(data)

        #grab the wanted data from the Tweet
        text = datajson['extended_tweet']['full_text']
        screen_name = datajson['user']['screen_name']
        tweet_id = datajson['id']
        created_at = parser.parse(datajson['created_at'])
        replying_to = datajson['in_reply_to_screen_name']

        #print out a message to the screen that we have collected a tweet
        #print("Tweet collected at " + str(created_at))
        print(text, screen_name, tweet_id, created_at, replying_to)

        #insert the data into the MySQL database
        #store_data(created_at, text, screen_name, tweet_id)

    except Exception as e:
       print(e)


auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(Consumer_Key, Consumer_Secret)
auth.set_access_token(Access_Token, Access_Token_Secret)
#Set up the listener. The 'wait_on_rate_limit=True' is needed to help   with        Twitter API rate limiting.
listener = StreamListener(api=tweepy.API(wait_on_rate_limit=True)) 
streamer = tweepy.Stream(auth=auth, listener=listener)
#print("Tracking: " + str(WORDS))
streamer.filter(follow = ['25073877'], encoding = 'utf8')
```

Sorry for the bad indentation if any.